# Emulation Implementing CPU instructions?

Tags: c, emulation

I'm trying to learn emulation programming. I've done a CHIP-8 emulator, Under 40 instructions, and lived because of my music. I'm now hoping to do something A bit more complex, like an SNES. The problem I'm encountering is the sheer number of CPU instructions. Looking through the [wiki.SuperFamicom.org 65c816 instruction listing](http://wiki.superfamicom.org/snes/show/65816+Reference#instructions), It look's like a pain in the rear. And I've seen notes here and there on various internet pages that the CPU is the easyest part of an emulator to impliment.

Under the assumption that it was so hard because I was doing it wrong, I looked around and found a simple implimentation: [SNES Emulator in 15 minutes](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/kuvat/programming_examples/nesemu1/trace/nesemu1.cc) which is about 900 lines of code. Easy enough to work through.

So then, from the [SNES Emulator in 15 minutes](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/kuvat/programming_examples/nesemu1/trace/nesemu1.cc) Source, I found where the CPU instructions are. It look's a lot simpler than what I was thinking. I dont really understand it, but it's a few lines of code as opposed to a large mass of code. First thing I notice is that the instructions only have 1 implimentation each. If you look at the table in [SuperFamicom](http://wiki.superfamicom.org/snes/show/65816+Reference#instructions) then you see that it has

```
ADC #const
ADC (_db_),X
ADC (_db_,X)
ADC addr
ADC long
...
```

And The emulator source for (I think) ALL of those is:

```
// Note: op 0x100 means "NMI", 0x101 means "Reset", 0x102 means "IRQ". They are implemented in terms of "BRK".
// User is responsible for ensuring that WB() will not store into memory while Reset is being processed.
unsigned addr=0, d=0, t=0xFF, c=0, sb=0, pbits = op<0x100 ? 0x30 : 0x20;

// Define the opcode decoding matrix, which decides which micro-operations constitute
// any particular opcode. (Note: The PLA of 6502 works on a slightly different principle.)
const unsigned o8 = op / 32, o8m = 1u << (op%32);
// Fetch op'th item from a bitstring encoded in a data-specific variant of base64,
// where each character transmits 8 bits of information rather than 6.
// This peculiar encoding was chosen to reduce the source code size.
// Enum temporaries are used in order to ensure compile-time evaluation.
#define t(w8,w7,w6,w5,w4,w3,w2,w1,w0) if( \
        (o8<1?w0##u : o8<2?w1##u  : o8<3?w2##u : o8<4?w3##u : \
         o8<5?w4##u : o8<6?w5##u  : o8<7?w6##u : o8<8?w7##u : w8##u) & o8m)

t(0,0xAAAAAAAA,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0xAAAAA2AA,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000) { c = t; t += A + P.C; P.V = (c^t) & (A^t) & 0x80; P.C = t & 0x100; }
```

In short, my General question:

- Condensing the phenomenal cosmic power of CPU instructions into an itty bitty piece of code

Questions specific to the SNES emulator in 15 minutes source (portion posted above):

- How does `t(0, 0xAAAAAAAA, 0x00000000, ....)` parse the instruction? I see the `if` statment, but I dont know where the number's for any of the arguments come from, or what they mean to the overall code.
- Why `o8 = op / 32` and `o8m = 1u << (op%32)`?
- The opcodes for `ADC` has `ADC #const` which has a 2 byte operand, or `ADC addr` which has a 3 byte operand. And the code `t(0, 0xAAAAAAAA, ...)` impliments both cases?

While I'm asking:

- what do the `dp`, `_dp_` and `sr` that appear in `ADC dp`, `ADC (_dp_)` and `ADC sr,S` mean?
- what is the difference between `ADC (_dp_,X)` and `ADC dp,X`? (probably redundand given the question above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer all of this, but `dp` stands for Direct Page, meaning that the instruction takes a single-byte operand which is a memory address within the Direct Page. Direct Page addressing is an extension of the Zero Page addressing mode of the 6502, where the single-byte addresses referred to memory locations `$00` through `$FF`. The 16-bit derivatives of the 6502 have a configuration register which basically relocates the Zero Page to an alternate location.f

In the wiki page you linked to, some of the `dp` in the table have underscores on them, and the others are in italics. I assume that they are all intended to be italic, and the wiki markup isn't working. A quick check of the Edit link supports this assumption (in the wiki source, they all have underscores). So don't read anything into that.

In 6502 assembly and derivatives of it, `ADC dp,X` means... let's take a concrete example instead... `ADC $10,X` means to add `$10` to the value in register `X` to obtain an address, then load a value from that address and add it to the accumulator. `ADC ($10,X)` adds an extra level of indirection: add `$10` to `X` to obtain an address, load a value from that address, interpret the loaded value as another address, and load the value from *that* address and add it to the accumulator. Parenthesized operands always add a level of indirection.

Note that the available modes include `(dp,X)` and `(dp),Y` and the placement of the parentheses relative to the comma and register is significant. With `(dp),Y` the value of `Y` is added to the first loaded value to get the address to use in the second load.

As for that emulator... code golf doesn't lead to enhanced readability! I don't think the portion you've posted is actually understandable by itself, and I don't feel like tracking down and reading the rest of it. But the key concept in the `t` macro is **bitstring**. Its arguments are a series of 9 bitmasks, each 32 bits long, for a total of 288 bits. Every possible opcode (256 of them), plus the 3 pseudo-opcodes mentioned in the first comment, is therefore represented by a single bit in this 288-bit-long bitstring, with 29 bits left over.

That explains the construction of `o8` and `o8m`. The 8-bit value is split into a 3-bit portion (to select an argument from the 8 arguments supplied to `t`) and a 5-bit portion (to select a single bit from the selected argument). The big `?:` chain does the first selection and the combination of `&` and `1 << ...` does the select selection.

And then, oh look we have a variable called `t` too. It's not related to the macro. Giving them the same name was just cruel.

Maybe I can figure out what that bitstring is doing. When the opcode is a low number, `o8` (the high bits) will be 0, so the `?:` chain will use `w0`, which is the **last** argument to the macro. As the opcode increases, the selected argument moves leftward through the argument list to `w1`, then `w2`... and the `o8m` selector likewise starts at the right and moves left (`& (1<<0)` is the rightmost bit, `& (1<<1)` is the next one, etc.) and the `if` condition will be true when the selected bit is 1. Values are:

```
0,          # opcodes $100 and up
0xAAAAAAAA, # opcodes $E0 to $FF
0x00000000, # opcodes $C0 to $DF
0x00000000, # opcodes $A0 to $BF
0x00000000, # opcodes $80 to $9F
0xAAAAA2AA, # opcodes $60 to $7F
0x00000000, # opcodes $40 to $5F
0x00000000, # opcodes $20 to $3F
0x00000000  # opcodes $00 to $1F
```

or in binary

```
0,                                  # opcodes $100 and up
0b10101010101010101010101010101010, # opcodes $E0 to $FF
0b00000000000000000000000000000000, # opcodes $C0 to $DF
0b00000000000000000000000000000000, # opcodes $A0 to $BF
0b00000000000000000000000000000000, # opcodes $80 to $9F
0x10101010101010101010001010101010, # opcodes $60 to $7F
0b00000000000000000000000000000000, # opcodes $40 to $5F
0b00000000000000000000000000000000, # opcodes $20 to $3F
0b00000000000000000000000000000000  # opcodes $00 to $1F
```

Reading each line from right to left, the 1's are in positions corresponding to these opcodes: `$61` `$63` `$65` `$67` `$69` `$6D` `$6F` `$71` `$73` `$75` `$77` `$79` `$7B` `$7D` `$7F` `$E1` `$E3` `$E5` `$E7` `$E9` `$EB` `$ED` `$EF` `$F1` `$F3` `$F5` `$F7` `$F9` `$FB` `$FD` `$FF`

Hmm... that sort of resembles the list of `ADC` and `SBC` opcodes, but some of them are wrong.

Oh (I finally gave up and looked at some more of the emulator code) that's a **NES** emulator, not a **SNES** emulator, so it only has 6502 opcodes.